# Match dates from list of data frames in R

Tags: r, date, time-series, match

I have a list of 100+ time series dataframes `my.list` with daily observations for each product in its own data frame. Some values are NA without any record of the date. I would like to update each data frame in this list to show the date and `NA` if it does not have a record on this date.

Dates:

```
start = as.Date('2016/04/08')
full <- seq(start, by='1 days', length=10)
```

Sample Time Series Data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(Date = seq(start, by ='2 days',length=5), Sales = c(5,10,15,20,25))
d2 <- data.frame(Date = seq(start, by= '1 day', length=10),Sales = c(1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
my.list <- list(d1, d2)
```

I want to merge all `full` date values into each data frame, and if no match exists then `sales` is NA:

```
   my.list

[[d1]]
Date    Sales
2016-04-08    5
2016-04-09    NA
2016-04-10    10
2016-04-11    NA
2016-04-12    15
2016-04-13    NA
2016-04-14    20
2016-04-15    NA
2016-04-16    25
2016-04-17    NA


[[d2]]
Date    Sales
2016-04-08    1
2016-04-09    2
2016-04-10    3
2016-04-11    4
2016-04-12    5
2016-04-13    6
2016-04-14    7
2016-04-15    8
2016-04-16    9
2016-04-17    10
```

Comment: This is essentially what you get with `merge` in base R, i.e. `merge(d1,d2,all.x=T,all.y=T, "Date")`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to update each of the dataframes in `my.list` to contain one row for each date given in the vector of dates `full`

#### Base R

In base R, `merge()` can be used as already mentioned by [Hack-R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575213/match-dates-from-list-of-data-frames-in-r#comment88159678_50575213). However, th answer below expands this to work on all dataframes in the list:

```
# creat dataframe from vector of full dates
full.df <- data.frame(Date = full)
# apply merge on each dataframe in the list
lapply(my.list, merge, y = full.df, all.y = TRUE)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>          Date Sales
> 1  2016-04-08     5
> 2  2016-04-09    NA
> 3  2016-04-10    10
> 4  2016-04-11    NA
> 5  2016-04-12    15
> 6  2016-04-13    NA
> 7  2016-04-14    20
> 8  2016-04-15    NA
> 9  2016-04-16    25
> 10 2016-04-17    NA
>
> [[2]]
>          Date Sales
> 1  2016-04-08     1
> 2  2016-04-09     2
> 3  2016-04-10     3
> 4  2016-04-11     4
> 5  2016-04-12     5
> 6  2016-04-13     6
> 7  2016-04-14     7
> 8  2016-04-15     8
> 9  2016-04-16     9
> 10 2016-04-17    10
> ```

#### Caveat

The answer assumes that `full` covers the overall range of `Date` of all dataframes in the list.

In order to avoid any mishaps, the overall range of `Date` can be retrieved from the available data in `my.list`:

```
overall_date_range <- Reduce(range, lapply(my.list, function(x) range(x$Date)))
full <- seq(overall_date_range[1], overall_date_range[2], by = "1 days")
```

---

#### Using `rbindlist()`

Alternatively, the list of dataframes which are identical in structure can be stored in a large dataframe. An additional attribute indicates to which product each row belongs to. The homogeneous structure simplifies subsequent operations.

The code below uses the `rbindlist()` function from the `data.table` package to create a large `data.table`. `CJ()` (*cross join*) creates all combinations of dates and product id which is then merged / joined to fill in the missing dates:

```
library(data.table)
all_products <- rbindlist(my.list, idcol = "product.id")[
  CJ(product.id = unique(product.id), Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "1 day")), 
  on = .(Date, product.id)]
all_products
```

> ```
>     product.id       Date Sales
>  1:          1 2016-04-08     5
>  2:          1 2016-04-09    NA
>  3:          1 2016-04-10    10
>  4:          1 2016-04-11    NA
>  5:          1 2016-04-12    15
>  6:          1 2016-04-13    NA
>  7:          1 2016-04-14    20
>  8:          1 2016-04-15    NA
>  9:          1 2016-04-16    25
> 10:          1 2016-04-17    NA
> 11:          2 2016-04-08     1
> 12:          2 2016-04-09     2
> 13:          2 2016-04-10     3
> 14:          2 2016-04-11     4
> 15:          2 2016-04-12     5
> 16:          2 2016-04-13     6
> 17:          2 2016-04-14     7
> 18:          2 2016-04-15     8
> 19:          2 2016-04-16     9
> 20:          2 2016-04-17    10
> ```

Subsequent operations can be grouped by `product.id`, e.g., to determine the number of valid sales data for each product:

```
all_products[!is.na(Sales), .(valid.sales.data = .N), by = product.id]
```

> ```
>    product.id valid.sales.data
> 1:          1                5
> 2:          2               10
> ```

Or, the totals sales per product:

```
all_products[, .(total.sales = sum(Sales, na.rm = TRUE)), by = product.id]
```

> ```
>    product.id total.sales
> 1:          1          75
> 2:          2          55
> ```

If required for some reason the result can be converted back to a list by

```
split(all_products, by = "product.id")
```

Comment: @STACKin, does this answer your question. If so, you may want to consider [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you.